# TFS2017 What determines the dotnet (core) build step versions available on perm?

Tags: tfs, .net-core, tfsbuild

What determines the version(s) of the build steps for ".net core" available in TFS2017 on prem?
I've patched tfs up to date, installed .net core version 2.2 on build and tfs servers, but I can only see v0.* and v1.* in the TFS build steps.
[image: TFS2017 Build Step Screenshot]

Edit to clarify: it's the version of the build step template I'm interested in, not sdk/framework/dotnet exe on the servers.

Comment: that's not the version of netcore but the version of the task that will invoke the netcode-sdk. try running a build to see if the task picks up the netcore2-sdk

Comment: to answer your question the versions of the buildsteps for "net core" are in no relation to the actual netcore-sdk installation

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, it's the build step version template that I'm interested in - not the dotnet core version on the build/tfs servers. I can't figure out what determines the version of the build steps that are available. For thrid party stuff like octopus it's easy - just update the extension on tfs, bingo new up to date build steps. For these I can't figure it out.

Comment: thats just the set of tasks that is supported and delivered for your specific version of tfs. with new versions of tfs come new tasks. the cloud-hosted variant (AzureDevOps) updates theese  automatically. you can update the tasks in tfs as well with newer versions of the tasks but i would't recommend this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasks are versioned, each task in a pipeline has a **Version** selector to let you choose the version you want. And you must specify the major version of the task used in your pipeline. This can help to prevent issues when new versions of a task are released.

> **Tasks are typically backwards compatible**, but in some scenarios you may encounter unpredictable errors when a task is automatically
>   updated.
>
> When a new minor version is released (for example, 1.2 to 1.3), your
>   build or release will automatically use the new version. However, if a
>   new major version is released (for example 2.0), your build or release
>   will continue to use the major version you specified until you edit
>   the pipeline and manually change to the new major version. The build
>   or release log will include an alert that a new major version is
>   available.

More details you could refer to this official link-- [Task versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#task-versions)

`What determines the dotnet (core) build step versions available on perm` Usually it's related with your TFS version. New version TFS include new version task by default. That make sense, since for some old TFS when it's released, the new version task is not release or in development.

For example with my Azure DevOps 2019 update1, you will be able to select version 2(latest) of this .NET Core CLI task.

[image]

If you really need the latest version, you could also consider package the task [DotNetCoreCLIV2](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/DotNetCoreCLIV2) and upload it by yourself. But we could not guarantee compatibility on old version TFS, some scenarios you may encounter unpredictable errors.

Comment: Thanks! That's a nice clear answer. I hoped I wouldn't have to update TFS beyond 2017 at this stage, but as we move into .Net Core development more and more being stuck with the old task versions is becoming more of an issue.

Comment: @SamClayton Yeah you should also get multiple new features and new UI designed in Azure DevOps. Also .NET Core 3.0 is start is widely used. High recommend you to upgrade to latest TFS version Azure DevOps 2019 under your situation.

Comment: You should be able to run any versions of dotnet core with the dotnet task, as long as the proper sdk is installed on you build server.  The version used is what is specified in you project file.